# Is it OK to follow a possessive determiner by the word "such"?

Tags: possessives, determiners

> - A file whose filename ends with a date-and-time suffix that is separated by @ is a copy that is created to compare it later with the current version of the file and **with other such copies of that file** by using a comparison utility.
> - A file whose filename ends with a date-and-time suffix that is separated by @ is a copy that is created to compare it later with the current version of the file and **with other its such copies** by using a comparison utility.
>
> ```
> aaa.txt
> aaa.txt@20110228-1359
> aaa.txt@20110228-1405
> ```

Are both of these versions grammatical? The second version is more concise but looks weird.

Comment: The first version is correct. If the specific word "such" wasn't present in version 1, that would simply mean you could compare later with *any* copies of a file, not just those using the "@ + date_time suffix" naming convention. Your second version is syntactic garbage, I'm afraid. In principle, ***with its other such copies*** is *probably* syntactically valid, but I don't think anyone would normally say / write that.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thanks :) Sorry for a late comment. If I change "with its other such copies" to "with its other @-copies" it still sounds weird?

Comment: *Technically speaking* it's probably "syntactically valid" to use ***with its other @-copies*** (without including the word ***such*** at all). But idiomatically speaking that's even less likely than the one in my first comment (which I don't think anyone would normally say / write).  If you're not comfortable with this (relatively "complex, formal, literary") use of the word ***such***, you CAN'T simply discard it. You need to do some much more radical rephrasing - *...with any other copies of that file **renamed in accordance with that same "@date-and-time" convention***, perhaps.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica What really bothers me is that [a] "current version of the file" and [b] "copies of that file" (or [b2] "copies of the same file") create a false parallelism. In [b], "of" means possession; in [a], it doesn't mean possession; and this is why I'm trying to get rid of one of these "of"-s.

Comment: (cont.) Another version I'm considering -- which doesn't have such an issue -- is "A file whose file name ends with a date-and-time suffix that is delimited by an at sign ***is a copy that is created to be compared with other such copies of the file or, most often, with its current version, by using a comparison utility.***" But I'm not sure it sounds idiomatically enough.

Comment: All your ideas about "of" and "possession" are completely irrelevant in this context (no native speaker would ever think like that). There is absolutely nothing wrong with the first version in your question text, and most likely ***all*** attempts to "improve" it are doomed to failure.

Comment: ...but on purely stylistic grounds I might rephrase part of the preceding text to *...that is created **for possible later comparison** with the current version **or** other such copies [of that file]* (those last 3 words being pointless, imho)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thanks a lot. (Really.)

Comment: Glad to help. There's not much point in being "answered" if you're still not sure about things. But probably the main point you should take away from this interaction is that in practice, the preposition ***of*** rarely has anything to do with "possession, ownership". It's far more important to grasp that point than to learn the full details of the relatively complex and uncommon use of ***such*** in your cited context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the second version is not correct.

The word "such" is being used here to specify that "other copies" only applies to copies that have the same timestamp suffix.  A more explicit version would be "with other timestamped copies of the same file".